# Complex regular expression ... AND OR, negation

Tags: regex, total-commander

I would like to search files by their content in Total Commander so I want to create a regex, but I cannot find any manual where it would really be explained. My situation is that I need something like this:

```
fileContains("<html>") && fileContains("{myVariable1}") && fileNotContains("<script>")
```

I can write cca this:

```
(<html>)+
({myVariable1})+
(<script>){0} ... but this does not work for me
```

And I cannot put it all together. Any ideas, please? Or do you have a link to an excellent regex explanation?

Answer (score 0):

try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/VWlZ4T/2):

```
(?=.*\{myVariable1\})(?=.*<html>)(?!.*<script>)
```

it's just 3 lookaheads in a row. one of those is a negative lookahead. Note the "single line" modifier to enable 'dot matches newline'.

edit (per comment):  I guess Total Commander's regex engine does not support lookarounds at all. While you *could* combine two positive lookaheads into an equivalent 'consuming' pattern with something like this untested regex: `(.*(\{myVariable1\}|<html>)){2}`, you cannot include the 'negated search' within a single regex unless you have a legitimate regex engine.

You could try [this Total Commander regex plug-in](http://totalcmd.net/plugring/PCREsearch.html):

> A RegEx content plug-in with Unicode support - based on Perl
>   Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) library. This plug-in may
>   replace TC's RegEx engine for file content

Comment: Total commander tells me that there is some error on position 20. If I try to use: (?=.*HELLO) the error is on position 10. Its hard for me to find any mistake as I do not understand your command.